# How we can upload Large file in chunks in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to upload a zip file of 350mb -  500mb to server. It gives "ENOSPC" error. 
Is it possible to upload file in chunks and receive it on server as one file ? 
or 
Use custom location for tmpfs, so that it will be independent of system tmp, because in my case tmp is of 128MB only.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Web-server uploading feature like [nginx-upload](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html) and apache-upload

Not sure what it is called in apache but I guess apache too has it

if you are using Nginx

there is also a [nginx-upload-progress](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule) which can be helpful if you want to track the progress of the upload

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks Viren, I had tried various methods to upload a Zip file of 550Mb on client's server, but was not able to get success.

Comment: Please Correct me i am wrong...  "I had noticed that when i am uploading a file(Via.. file class, paperclip, carrierwave and jquery), it uses tmp file system, which is of 128Mb and we cann't modify change it. Even when i am uploading a file of 68Mb, it doesn't upload because when file upload 100% then tmpfile is converted into original file and tmpfs uses double space for a single moment". ... this is what i had noticed by uploading file and checking disk space. So plz tell me any alternate for uploading without changing Tmpfs

Comment: @user1659407 I'm trying to understand what you actually meant over here is it you have 128 MB limit for tmp directory and when uploading a 64 MB file it getting written twice is that your question If that your question I guess that is because the I guess the way RacMMultiPart work check over here `https://github.com/chneukirchen/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/multipart/uploaded_file.rb#L17` so in your case `path` and the `@tempfile.path` i guess are same hence the temp memory getting double